# Does it make sense to have both chrome and chromium tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [google-chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) (41) and [chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/chromium) (32). Seeing as they are basically the same product, the main difference being the branding, does it make sense to have them under two tags on our site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We should keep them seperate, there are more differences than branding.

Chrome is provided by a third party and supported by Google, whereas Chromium is built in Ubuntu using Launchpad, Launchpad Translations, etc.

Someone asking about a flash problem would have a totally different answer depending on if they had chrome or chromium, for example.

- [What's the difference between Google Chrome and/or Chromium? What are the advantages/disadvantages to each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advanta)

Comment: Agreed. They are very similar but also very different in some subsystems like flash and PDFs.