# Relevancy of openoffice.org tags

Tags: discussion

Now that LibreOffice is going to replace OOo while being the same, I find it irrelevant to have any OOo tags. They should be merged with LibreOffice's tags at least by the time on Natty's release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disagree. While, yes Natty will ship with LibreOffice by default, it doesn't mean that everyone is going to auto-upgrade to Natty at release date especially if they're going by LTS. 10.04 will still exist and will exist as the LTS for quite some time. So a merge of these tags seems premature for now.

Also, it's not just about support issues, questions like "How do I sent a patch to OpenOffice" would different than LibreOffice, or roadmap questions, or any other question about the projects themselves.

Comment: That is true, but other than the name and branding, the issues and solutions are unlikely to change until the next major update.

Comment: @Jorge, post that comment as an answer - I find it the most relevant reason to keep OOo tags around.

Comment: @Oxwivi I've just updated Marco's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit like [the chromium and Google Chrome question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1020/does-it-make-sense-to-have-both-chrome-and-chromium-tags).

In an ideal world we'd merge them. But doing so isn't really the right thing (as Marco and Jorge) explained.

Comment: Chromium and Chrome are different from this case - here both of them are open-source, and so are how they work and core structures, and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

From the meta.unix.SE: [Does merging libreoffice and openoffice make sense?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/does-merging-libreoffice-and-openoffice-make-sense).

The answer there: `/openoffice` was kept with a synonym for `/libreoffice` created.

Answer (score 0):

It's another case of them still being different products. The tags are not supposed to be generic. A tag for OpenOffice should indicate a question about OpenOffice. If they use LibreOffice, the tag should be LibreOffice.

And while we are here to support Ubuntu, we're not limited to the default applications in Ubuntu (although they'll probably be the main support topics). A change in defaults shouldn't ever mean we need to change our tagging regimes.